# Why rstrip don't modify list of strings

Tags: python

Why rstrip don't modify list of strings named instrumentList

```
for instrument in instrumentList:
    instrument = instrument.rstrip()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, a `str` is immutable; you *cannot* change it in place. You can see this with `id` (same `id` means same object):

```
>>> instrument = "guitar "
>>> id(instrument)
50103936
>>> instrument = instrument.strip()
>>> id(instrument)
49968576 # different object
```

`rstrip` returns a *new `str` object*, assigning this to `instrument` doesn't change the list the object also referenced by `instrument` is in; the list still references the old object:

```
>>> instruments = ["guitar "]
>>> id(instruments[0])
50103968
>>> instrument = instruments[0]
>>> instrument = instrument.rstrip()
>>> id(instrument)
49968576 # different object
>>> id(instruments[0])
50103968 # still the same in list
```

A list *is* mutable, so if you have a list of objects you *can* change it in-place, i.e. without creating a new object, for example by adding a new item:

```
>>> instruments = ["guitar"]
>>> id(instruments)
50116048
>>> instruments.append("piano")
>>> instruments
['guitar', 'piano'] # more items
>>> id(instruments)
50116048 # same object
```

Or (which is what you want to do), change which object a particular index references:

```
for index, instrument in enumerate(instruments):
    instruments[index] = instrument.rstrip() # assign new object back into list
```

Although ramcdougal's list comprehension is certainly neater.

Answer (score 3):

You are redefining the local `instrument` instead of changing the value in the list.

Try:

```
instrumentList = [instrument.rstrip() for instrument in instrumentList]
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, I am constructing a replacement list instead of modifying your original list in place. It would be more memory efficient to change the list in place, but that only really becomes an issue if you have a few hundred million instruments.

Comment: On the same subject, if there are other things with references to the list so that you *have* to modify the list in place, then the simplest change to make that happen is `instrumentList[:] = [same replacement list]`. jonrsharpe's code doesn't have to construct a second large list so might be good for memory use. But it does use indexes so the code is a bit worse to read.

Answer (score 0):

jonrsharpe's answer is excellent, I just want to point out an other concise way to do it with `map`:

```
from string import rstrip
instruments_stripped = map(rstrip, instruments)
```

Like list comprehension this will create a new list.

Comment: Note that this will create a `map` object in Python 3.x, not a `list`

Comment: @jonrsharpe: no it won't, because `from string import rstrip` will fail in Python 3 ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop good point well made! In 3.x, use `list(map(str.rstrip, instruments))` (heck, as this will work in 2.x, perhaps just always use it).